# count the number of datarows per month in a list

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight

Programming in silverlight/c#.

Let's say I have a list containing the number of accepted/declined sales per month for the last 6 months (updated in real time):

```
List<data> merge = new List<data>();

public class data
{
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string event_action_cd { get; set; }
    public string quote_id { get; set; }    
}
```

so my list will look something like this:

(Jan, accept, 1

Jan, accept, 2

Jan, decline, 3

Feb, accept, 4 ...

I want to return a aggregated list that has the month name and the percentage of accepted for that month.  Is there a elegant way to do that?  The hardest is figuring out what the last 6 months are (as they change from month to month), then I could probably run a loop with a counter for each accept/decline.

Comment: How much control do you have over your `data` class?  Could you change `month` from a string to an `int` or a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(from d in merge
group d by d.month into g
select new 
   {
       Month = g.Key, 
       Total = g.Count, 
       Accepted = g.Count(x => x.event_action_cd =="accept")*100/g.Count
   }).ToList()
```

Comment: weird - is there a reason why i cant use tolist() on after this query?

Comment: it seems Accepted (which is the percentage) is greater than 100?

Comment: I updated it, to calculate Accepted, you need to divide by g.Count, not the other way around, so it should not be greater than 100. And you should be able to do .ToList()

Comment: got it- thx had to add brackets around the whoel thing to be able to cast to list